# How to calculate the energy of conduction band and valence band with respect to vacuum in quantum espresso?

Tags: quantum-espresso

I was able to calculate band energies in quantum espresso. How to convert them to values that are in terms of difference from vacuum energy?

Answer (score 12):

First of all, you need to find where the vacuum energy level is. To that purpose, you first need to calculate the planar average of the electrostatic potential [like the following figure](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2014/cp/c4cp01975j#!divAbstract):

[image]

from which you can find the vacuum energy level. How to obtain this figure with Quantum Espresso?

- Self-consistent calculation with pw.x.
- [Postprocessing with pw.x.](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PP.html#idm22)

  ```
   &INPUTPP
     outdir='./tmp'
     plot_num=11
     filplot='pp11.dat'
   /
  ```
- Take the planar average of the electrostatic potential with [average.x.](https://github.com/QEF/q-e/blob/master/PP/src/average.f90)

Comment: If the question author is asking about band energies from a bulk calculation, you should also align the potential at the center of the slab with that of the bulk calculation as well.

Comment: Along which axis is this diagram? and How do I define it?

Comment: @AshiqueLal z direction

Comment: What is the unit for the output of average.x?

Comment: @franz I approved your edit, but can you take a look at my last edit and let me know if it's correct?

Comment: The postprocessing should be done with the code pp.x not pw.x, else I think its is fine @NikeDattani.

Comment: @franz so my last edit needs to be reverted?

Comment: Is your answer complete? I actually wonder how large the vacuum region has to be and at what distance from the film you have to calculate the planar average of the potential. I mean, the electrostatic interaction has a long range. One probably has to introduce a large vacuum region to extract the quantity in this way. I would have assumed that there are extrapolation schemes that are more efficient.

Comment: @NikeDattani the code order should be pw.x, pp.x, average.x.